# Copy transforms from one object to another

Tags: transforms

I want an object to have the same Transforms (location, rotation, and scale) as another object. How can I copy the Transforms from one object to another?

[image: Blender]

Answer (score 61):

1. Select the object you wish to move
2. While the First object is selected, SHIFT Select the other object
3. Go to the transforms panel

   [image: transform area]
4. Right click in the Location properties

   - Copy to selected
   - Note: You only need to do this for one of the axis, blender will automatically do the other axis as well

   [image: menu]
5. Repeat step 4 for Rotation and Scale

Comment: I'm using version 2.79b and the options that appear are "Copy All To Selected" and "Copy Single To Selected". As their names suggest, "Copy All" copies all X,Y,Z values at once, whereas "Copy Single" copies from just the axis you right-clicked on. That's a pretty neat feature and very useful for alignment.

Comment: Applicable to 2.8x as well. "Copy All To Selected" is available.

Comment: Man this is THE answer.

Comment: Yo, working on 3.3, thaaaanks!!!

Answer (score 19):

For this kind of task the **[Copy Attributes Menu Addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Copy_Attributes_Menu)** is very good. It comes with Blender.

After enabling it, simply:

- Select your object
- With <kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed, select the target object
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Select **Copy Location** from the list

If needed, do the same for rotation and scale as well.

Comment: The Target Object listed in the instructions is the object with the values that you want to keep and not the object to have it's values overwritten.

Answer (score 3):

The Location, Rotation and Scale used for each object is available in the object properties and also the N panel in the 3D viewport. You can easily copy and paste each XYZ setting to get two objects lined-up, however this does not work with multiple objects (for that, see answers above). Simply hover over the value, copy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. Then hover over the next value, and paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.  You can even copy and paste all three XYZ values at once by adding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key! <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy all three values. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste all three values. This works in Blender 2.8+, and even in 2.79b.

[image]

The same values are also available in the Properties Sidebar in the 3DView which you can view by pressing <kbd>N</kbd>

Note: this will align each object based on the location of the objects Origin Point. This point may not be located where you expect and can be adjusted. [See the manual on object centre](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects#Object_Centers)

Comment: Thanks! Did you know that you can also copy all three XYZ values at once by hovering, press Ctrl+Alt+C, and then select your other object and hover over the values and press Ctrl+Alt+V? This is amazing. Tested in 2.82.

Comment: @CobyRandal, thanks a lot - that is really what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entire skelecton/bone structure copied. Select one bone in the source skelecton, then press A to slect all bones. Press CTRL+A Go to your target object and select a single bone. Press CTRL+V and the bones will be overwritten with the bones from the first object.

Answer (score -1):

One more option you can try is with an addon. It was published just yesterday so I haven't had a chance to try myself, but it looks like it might fit the bill here.

http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/76682