# Object as camera

Tags: rendering, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine, camera

Can anyone tell me why i can't render from the object as camera mode (meaning i select a model lets say a Suzanne for example and i want to render from that perspective). can anyone supply me with source code of this feature i am willing to work with it.

Comment: do you mean as wireframe? Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. Add reference [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @cegaton i edited for more detail like requested i've tried before and couldn't i don't have a blender file in front of me at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps 'Object as Camera' should be called 'View from Object'. The selected object does not become a camera, with all the attributes of a camera, such as focal length and sensor size. You can dolly it, but you can't zoom it. Nor can you, for example, set your object to give you an orthographic view.

The perspective transform seems to be hard-coded for convenient use in the viewport, the only accessible variables in it being the location and rotation of the pivot-point of the object. (Perhaps someone who knows where to look can confirm this, and tell us what the field of view is set to). The function seems only intended to help with various tasks in the 3D View, such as aiming lights.

Maybe your best option is to create a real camera and [copy the transforms](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7388/copy-transforms-from-one-object-to-another)
of your object to it, and/or or put a Copy Transforms constraint on it.